# Design pattern for rating engine

Tags: design-patterns

can you please point to any good design patterns/frameworks to code the following system, preferably in java/scala/spring : A a kind of rating engine that will take about 100+ parameters with a range of options and do lots of computation/business logic to come up with some rating numbers. The business variables are also subject to change as well as business rules. I have seen similar engines in insurance and banking sector but never coded one.
Thanks a lot #designpatterns

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't offer a lot of details. However, it does sound like requirements can and will change. So a good pattern to plan for requirement changes is the Strategy pattern.

The goal of the Strategy pattern is to encapsulate an algorithm so that you can easily swap that algorithm. The rest of the code that relies on the strategy won't need to be modified. Another benefit is that the strategy can be switched at runtime. I highly recommend the GoF book.